# Does @Transactional annotation work on package-private methods with proxy?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-transactions

The Spring's Data Access documentation says:

> - Register a custom AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource with the
> - publicMethodsOnly flag set to false to enable support for
> - protected and package-private @Transactional methods in
> - class-based proxies.

And now I wonder, if the `@Transactional` will work in the below example or not. If not, then should I register this custom `AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource` or rather modify the method with the annotation to be public?

```
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

class ServiceA {
    private final ServiceA self;

    ServiceA(ServiceA self) {
        this.self = self;
    }

    void foo() {
        self.bar();
    }

    @Transactional
    void bar() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: No. Only for `public` and `protected` methods. the `private` and `default` methods cannot be proxied. So by default that won't work.

Comment: @M.Deinum so the class can be `default`, but the method where is `@Transactional` used should be `public` or `protected`, yes?

Comment: That should work, in theory.

Comment: @M.Deinum The documentation says to consider the tip in the following paragraph for class-based proxies or consider using AspectJ compile-time or load-time weaving.

If I do have `self` then I call this method by a bean proxy, so shouldn't it force Spring Aspect to handle `@Transactional`?

Comment: No you can still use a proxy.

Comment: @M.Deinum How I can test if the `@Transactional` does not work in my case? Is there an easy way for an INT test? I checked also `TransactionSynchronizationManager.isActualTransactionActive()` and it returns true, so does it mean it works as expected?

Comment: There wouldn't be any data in the database if it didn't work, as you can only persist/change data with a transaction.